# Solving non-linear second order differential equation: radius of curvature $= k \theta$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, plane-curves, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to find any curve where the radius of curvature increases linearly with angular displacement. So in polar coordinates

radius of curvature $= k \theta$

$$ \frac{(r^2 + r'^2)^{3/2}}{r^2 + 2r'^2 - rr''} = k \theta$$

where k is a constant

I just need a single curve that fits this equation, does not matter if it is defined as an integral or power series. But, best to have a closed form solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are looking for any curve satisfying the property $$\rho=k\theta$$
Therefore choose a curve which has the property that the radius vector makes a constant angle $\alpha$ with the tangent vector. In intrinsic form, we have $$\frac {dy}{dx}=\tan\psi$$
The radius of curvature is $$\rho=\frac{ds}{d\psi}$$
Your curve therefore has the property that $\rho=k(\psi-\alpha)$. 
We can now use the well-known relationships $$x=\int\rho\cos\psi d\psi$$ and $$y=\int\rho\sin\psi d\psi$$
to obtain $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\theta$ and then you can get the curve easily into polar form.

Comment: Is log spiral with constant $ \alpha$ a solution?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, taking alpha to be 0, the integrals give r = k * sqrt(theta^2 + 1)  I believe. But, when substituted into the radius of curvature formula, this does not give k * theta. Im i making some mistake?

Comment: @user240675| using integration by parts, and setting $x=0$, $y=0$  when $\theta=0$ gives a more complicated expression for $r$ than the one you found, even if you put $\alpha=0$

Comment: ψ−α = θ. So for convenience choose α = 0. So ψ = θ. then x = kψsinψ + kcosψ ; y = ksinψ - kψcosψ;  And r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2) So r = k * sqrt(ψ^2 + 1). And substitue this into (r2+r′2)3/2r2+2r′2−rr′′= ??. ?? =/= kψ

Comment: What initial values are you using @user240675? I get something different

Comment: Oh, I omitted the constant C when integrating x and y. I m trying to do it again, with the initial condition  x=0, y=0 when θ=0

Comment: @user240675 thought so! Have fun finding the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If $\psi $ is angle between radius vector and tangent and primes are taken with respect to arc length, then we need to solve for $ r,\theta $ via $ \psi$ for reciprocal radius of curvature:

$$ \dfrac{d \psi}{ds} + \dfrac{\sin \psi}{r} = k\, \int  \dfrac{\sin \psi}{r} ds, \, r^{'} = \cos \psi,\, \theta^{'}= \dfrac{\sin \psi}{r}.  $$

EDIT1:
As a first step numerical solution is given below for assumed boundary conditions near origin.

[image: Spiral Rad_prop_$\theta$]

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, the primes are differentiation wrt theta.

Comment: Yes, primes you gave were wrt theta, I had given primes wrt arc.